# Como fazer validação de um array se ele possui objetos dentro dele ou não? React JS

Tags: javascript, react, dom, redux, jsx

Tenho um código feito usando React JS e funciona assim, tenho um componente select, e este é reutilizado várias vezes e as informações que ele recebe sempre vem de um array, só que agora preciso mandar um array de objetos como pode ser ver:

```js
const plans = [{"text" : "PRO","value" : 1},{"text" : "PRO","value" : 1}]
```

Aqui eu chamando meu componente e fazendo ele receber os valores desse array de objetos:

```js
<Select
    onChange={value => setQuery(Object.assign(query, { tipoUsuario: value }))}
    placeholder="Selecione o plano"
    items={plans}
/>
```

Aqui o meu componente:

```js
export default props => {
    return (
        <div className="inline-block relative w-64">
            <select
                onChange={input => props.onChange(input.target.value)}
                className="block appearance-none w-full bg-white border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded shadow leading-tight focus:outline-none"
            >
                <option>{props.placeholder}</option>
                {props.items.map((element, key) => {
                    return <option key={key} value={element.value}>{element.text}</option>
                })}
            </select>
    )
}
```

Eu preciso que esse meu componente consiga receber meu array de objetos, só que ao receber ele precisar fazer uma verificação se é um array comum ou se é um array com objetos dentro, pois dessa forma ai ele recebe tranquilamente o objeto, só que quando eu preciso de um select que só utiliza um array simples a a aplicação quebra, ai preciso dessa verificação para que quando não for um array com objetos meu componente seria dessa forma:

`<option key={key}>{element}</option>`

Já pesquisei pra caramba e não achei nada que conseguisse me ajudar.

**Solução:**

````js
export default props => {
    return (
        <div className="inline-block relative w-64">
            <select
                onChange={input => props.onChange(input.target.value)}
                className="block appearance-none w-full bg-white border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded shadow leading-tight focus:outline-none"
            >
                {props.placeholder && <option>{props.placeholder}</option>}
                <ListOptions items={props.items} />
            </select>
    )
}

const ListOptions = ({ items }) => {
    if (items)
        return items.map(element => {
            return typeof element === 'string' ? (
                <option>{element}</option>
            ) : (
                <option key={element.value} value={element.value}>
                    {element.text}
                </option>
            )
        })
    return <option>None</option>
}```
````

Comment: Oi Anderson, tudo bem? Cara, eu não entendi muito bem seu código. Tipo, você tem um componente `<Select />` que recebe como itens a **constante plans**. Porque ela muda de array pra array de objetos? Teria como detalhar melhor o código até mesmo mostrando o método completo? A resposta do @HelloWorld funciona, mas as vezes uma simples mudança aí poderia nem precisar de adicionar mais uma função.

Comment: Não é só um componente <Select />, existem mais dois, e esses dois recebem um array comum, enquanto somente um deles recebe esse array de objeto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se todos os dados de cada índice do teu array forem do mesmo tipo, tu pode verificar o tipo de um dos indices e com base nisso escolher qual tipo de option tu vai renderizar.

Pode verificar assim:

```
if(typeof(element[0]) === 'object') {
   renderOption1()
} else {
   renderOption2()
}
```